# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vimeo'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using typescript v^3.4.2, in an express app (^4.14.1), using node v11.3.0.

When I run my build for typescript, I get the following error:

```sh
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vimeo'. '/Users/me/Code/MyServer/node_modules/vimeo/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vimeo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vimeo';`

1 import { Vimeo } from "vimeo";
```

I am using the Vimeo api client for nodejs [vimeo.js](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js), version 2.1.1.

I've attempted to run `yarn add --dev @types/vimeo`, but unfortunately that library is for the *other* vimeo library, [vimeo/player.js](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js). Installing it is of no use.

I've tried to follow [this article](https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2018/02/28/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/) on creating my own custom type declaration.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "controllers/**/*", "routes/**/*", "models/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "types"]
}
```

And I've created: `/Users/me/Code/MyServer/types/vimeo/vimeo.d.ts`, which contains:

```
declare module vimeo {}
```

When I add that the error changes to:

```sh
yarn run v1.15.2
$ yarn build
$ tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix
$ tsc
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'vimeo'.
```

The article also suggests adding a root `global.d.ts` with the same definition in it, but that has no effect.

I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

(This is my package.json scripts block:)

```
 "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "yarn build",
    "start": "babel-node dist/app.js --presets es2015",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

And here's my `tslint.json`:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "trailing-comma": [false],
    "curly": [true, "ignore-same-line"],
    "ban-types": false
  },
  "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Comment: I would strongly urge you to get onto the most recent Node LTS version soon as possible. Node 11 was never an LTS release, and even Node 12 will drop off the support schedule _entirely_ in a few weeks when Node 18 becomes the current version, with Node 14 then being the oldest still-in-support version of Node.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, setting `"noImplicityAny": false,` can solve the issue of declaration files... or you can look for some `.d.ts` for that module (or even make your own and do a pull request in GitHub)